# How to alter a table using an SQL schema?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, go, sqlx

I'm using [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) to connect my MySQL database to Golang. I've got an SQL schema where all the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...` statements are defined. Here an example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users`
  (
     `id` INT(0) NOT NULL auto_increment,
     `language_code` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
     `premium` BIT(0) DEFAULT 0,
     `status` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     `user_id` INT(0) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
...
```

Here how I connect to database and I execute all the queries everytime:

```
Database, err = sqlx.Connect(Config.Database.Type, Config.Database.DataSourceString) // Connect to the database

if err != nil { // If there's an error, handle it
    panic(err.Error())
}

defer Database.Close() // Close the database when the function finishes

schemaSQL, err := ioutil.ReadFile("schema.sql") // Read the configuration file (DealsFinderBot/config.yaml)

if err != nil { // If there's an error, handle it
    panic(err.Error())
}

for _, query := range strings.Split(string(schemaSQL), ";") { // Loop on the queries of the schema
    if strings.TrimSpace(query) != "" { // If the query is not empty
        Database.MustExec(query) // Execute the query
    }
}
```

I would like to update every time (*alter a table*) everytime I add a new column or I edit some parameters (like `NOT NULL` or `DEFAULT ''`). How could I do this?

Comment: like re-run `schema.sql` without restarting the application?

Comment: @BorisSchegolev I'd lose all the data I've stored

Comment: Oh, you mean how to create changes? Take a look at DB versioning tools like FlyWay.

Comment: @BorisSchegolev I'll do, thank you